# Minimum of array function?

Tags: delphi

What I'm doing wrong exactly here ? It returns 0 each time I give it 5 numbers for some reasons

```
var
  I : integer;
  Ligne : array[1..5] of integer;

function   MinArray( var A : array of integer) : integer;
var I,min : integer;
begin
  min := A[1];
  for I := 1 to 5 do
    if A[I] < min then
      min := A[I] ;
  writeln(min);
end;

begin
  for I := 1 to 5 do
    readln(Ligne[I]);

  MinArray(Ligne);
  sleep(50000);
end.
```

If I take it off the function , It works just fine and it gives me the correct answer however when I try to use a function , I can't get it to work.

Comment: Could you perhaps unrandomize your code indentation to make it easier to read?

Comment: You really should learn how to use the debugger. (You tagged this Delphi, which means you must have one.) It would allow you to figure out this sort of problem in less time than you spent coming here and posting your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must assign a `Result` to the function:

```
function MinArray( var A : array of integer) : integer;
var I : integer;
begin
  Result := A[Low(A)];
  for I := Low(A) + 1 to High(A) do
    if A[I] < Result then
      Result := A[I] ;    
end;

begin
  ...
  WriteLn(MinArray(Ligne));
  ...
end.
```

Note that the array passed will be indexed from 0 to 4 in the function.
See [Open array parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters). This is the reason to the behaviour of `WriteLn(min);` in your code. By chance, the out of range A[5] returns zero.

Turn on {$R+} to add range check while debugging. Always!

Comment: If it returns 0 to 4 , how come you didn't do High(A) +1 ?

Comment: High(A) + 1 is 5 and out of bounds. The reason I start with Low(A) + 1 ( which is 1) is that the first value is already in the Result variable.